# Block the index page of the REST API in Tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

Is it possible to block the index page of the API? I don't want to display all the resources like that to none authenticated users? Right now, if people do for example:

http://example.com/api/rest/?format=json

They will see every possible resources within the API!

Comment: You want to disable it, or you want to secure it so only authenticated users can access it?

Comment: Either one is fine... As long as it is at least authenticated!

Answer (score 0):

do you look at tatsypie authorization manual. If not look at this [Tatsypie Authorization](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authorization.html#usage)